# Thinner Bootstrap progress bars?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress

How can I make the progress bars thinner with Bootstrap 3.0? I'm thinking how the YouTube like/dislike meter looks (the blue bar). I've tried searching for any CSS tricks but could not find anything.

Comment: Share some code please as I am not sure I understand what you want. Reducing the padding or something should do the trick.

Comment: I was looking at this: http://metroui.org.ua/progress-bar.html (Specifically the second blue bar). But I was hoping there was a quick way to just implement it without installing their customized Bootstrap.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As easy as doing this:

```
.progress {height: 10px;}
```

See: [Reduce the height of progress bar](http://jsbin.com/xayuy/1/edit?html,css,output)

Extra, if you want to show the text inside the progress bar:

```
.progress {height: 20px;} // we increased it so the text is visible or change font size
.progress .sr-only { position: relative; }
```

See: [Show text inside progress bar](http://jsbin.com/sowexo/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: If you use text inside the progress bar you can vertically align it with `.progress-bar { line-height: 10px; }`

Answer (score 6):

Shina is right, I just would like to add, it may be in some cases necessary to add the !important command to make the change apply over the already set parameter of the "progress" class, like this:

```
.progress {height: 10px !important;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create `.progress-sm`(Small progress) and `.progress-lg` (Large progress) css custom class in your stylesheet according to following and then use it's easily.

```
.progress-sm{
  height: 0.5rem !important;
}
.progress-lg{
  height: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

**For Small**

```
<div class="progress progress-sm">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

**For Default**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

**For Large**

```
<div class="progress progress-lg">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.progress-sm {
  height: 0.5rem!important;
}

.progress-lg {
  height: 1.5rem!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h5>For Small</h5>
<div class="progress progress-sm">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<br>
<h5>For Default</h5>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<br>
<h5>For Large</h5>
<div class="progress progress-lg">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You could just also use:

`<div class='.progress-sm'> ...your code ... </div>`

I believe it is the best solution, since you'll use a bootstrap class.

Comment: class names should not start with `.`.
`progress-sm` is not a valid bootstrap class, but would need to be created.